# Geocoding results formatting in Sheets

Tags: json, google-sheets, google-api

Good day, I am having some trouble getting my code to do what I want, I have a spreadsheet that I have loaded on Google Sheets, I have 3 columns, Column A is the name of the company, column B is Latitude and C is longitude. I have created a 4th column that should house the results of the API query I run that returns a JSON value to show the nearest city for the coordinates. This is the code that I run,
`=IMPORTJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="&B2&","&C2&"&key=MYAPIKEY","/results/")`

I have replaced my actual API key for obvious reasons, my results show all the values that the request returns, I can edit the code to /results/address_components and it narrows down the results but the results are still a few columns and rows big, I just want the query to return the "locality,political" address_component result, what am I missing?

I have tried replacing the end of the query with different request types but nothing else returns values.

Comment: The type I want to return is locality,political, I can only seem to filter the result down to formatted_address, however that is still to much data, I just want the locality,political type to be returned

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `&result_type=locality` right after your API key in the request and use the `/results/formatted_address` to give you a nice clean output.

If you need to do multiple requests at the same time just modify your code to join the results in the same cell like this:

```
=JOIN(",", IMPORTJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="&Sheet1!B2&","&Sheet1!C2&"&key=APIKEY&result_type=locality","/results/formatted_address"))
```